imagen se borra al recargar la pagina en jsp
estoy usando jsp en netbeans, al iniciar sesion se muestra correctamente:
Pero al recargar la pagina ya sea dando F5 o yendo a otra pagina y volviendo, esta desaparece:
lo que hago al iniciar sesion es
User loggedUser = daoUser.login(user);

        if (loggedUser != null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("user", loggedUser);
            response.sendRedirect("feed.jsp"); 

y daoUser obtiene de la base datos la informacion y hace sets
 rs = pst.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                loggedUser = new User();
                loggedUser.setIdUser(rs.getInt("ID"));
                loggedUser.setUser(rs.getString("Username"));
                loggedUser.setPicProfile(rs.getBinaryStream("PicProfile"));
                loggedUser.setPassword(rs.getString("Password"));
            }

una vez hecho esto redirige a la pagina principal donde tengo esta validacion:
<% 
   Object user = request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
   if (user == null) {
       response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
   } else {
   String username = ((User) user).getUser();
      InputStream picProfileStream = ((User) session.getAttribute("user")).getPicProfile();
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = picProfileStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
byte[] picProfileBytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
String picProfileBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(picProfileBytes);

%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">...

<script>
    var username = '<%= username %>';
    var usernameSpan = document.getElementById("userNav");
    if (usernameSpan) {
        usernameSpan.textContent = username;
        usernameSpan.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
    var picProfile = '<%= picProfileBase64%>';
    var imgElement = document.getElementById('picProfileFeed');
        
    imgElement.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + picProfile;

</script>

basicamente lo que hace es obtener el atributo user de la sesion, en donde username es un string y picProfile es ByteArrayInputStream, entonces picProfile es convertido a base64 para para ponerlo en el src de la imagen. lo raro es que el username si persiste apesar de recargar la pagina pero la imagen no

Ya lo resolvi, se debia a que lo guardaba como un input stream, lo que pasa es que el input stream se consume en secuencia y una vez que es leido todo, se considera "consumido" y no puede ser leído de nuevo.
Lo solucione convirtiendo ese inputstream en byte[], de esta manera la informacion persiste
